# Delete row from mysql through generated table with records

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I am using 2 pages. On one page it generates a table with the records and a delete button. After pressing delete it goes to the second page which should delete the record. But it doesn't. Below is the code that I am using.

PS: The code is adapted from a tutorial I found through Google a while ago.

delete_overzicht.php

```
<?php
// Load Joomla! configuration file
require_once('../../../configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
// Get the required codes from the configuration file
$server = $config->host;
$username   = $config->user;
$password   = $config->password;
$database = $config->db;
// Connect to db
$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,$database);
// Get results
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cypg8_overzicht");

echo "<table border='1' id='example' class='tablesorter'><thead><tr><th>Formulier Id</th><th>Domeinnaam</th><th>Bedrijfsnaam</th><th>Datum</th><th>Periode</th><th>Subtotaal</th><th>Dealernaam</th><th>Verwijderen</th></tr></thead><tbody>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['formuliernummer'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['domeinnaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['bedrijfsnaam'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['periode'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td> &euro; " . $row['subtotaal'] . "</td>";        
  echo "<td>" . $row['dealercontactpersoon'] . "</td>";     
  echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>Verwijderen </a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php
// Load Joomla! configuration file
require_once('../../../configuration.php');
// Create a JConfig object
$config = new JConfig();
// Get the required codes from the configuration file
$server = $config->host;
$username   = $config->user;
$password   = $config->password;
$database = $config->db;
// Connect to db
$con = mysqli_connect($server,$username,$password,$database);
if (!$con){
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
mysqli_select_db($con,$database);

// Check whether the value for id is transmitted
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

// Put the value in a separate variable
$id = $_GET['id'];

// Query the database for the details of the chosen id
$result = mysqli_query($con,"DELETE * FROM cypg8_overzicht WHERE id = $id");

} else {
die("No valid id specified!");
}
?>
```

Thanks to everyone who is willing to help!

Comment: The syntax for DELETE is `DELETE FROM` - you need to remove the `*`

Comment: Do **NOT** do delete operations with a GET query: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Comment: @andrewski thanks for that answer. It was right on the money. It works great. Do you mind to post it as the answer. So that I can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the warning. I am delighted that you try to help me. It would be very nice from you if you could show me how to do it instead. Because I have no idea. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarcB how is it safe to implement the delete operations?

Comment: as a get, on a publicly available page, you're utterly unsafe. Even a simple browser "prefetch the links to save loading time later" will annihilate data. You **NEVER** put up a link that has permanent consequences unless it's at least protected by being POST-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer comes from the user Andrewsi. This answer was posted in the comments.

The syntax for DELETE is `DELETE FROM` - you need to remove the `*`